# DB2 count distinct on multiple columns

Tags: date, count, db2, distinct, resultset

I am trying to find count and distinct of multiple values but its not worikng in db2

select count(distinct col1, col2) from table

it throws syntax error that count has multiple columns.
any way to achieve this

```
column 1 column 2 date
1             a   2022-12-01
1             a   2022-12-01
2              a  2022-11-30
2              b  2022-11-30
1             b   2022-12-01

i want output

column1 column2 date        count
1         a      2022-12-01  2
2         a      2022-11-30  1
2         b      2022-11-30  1
1         a      2022-12-01  1
```

Comment: I don't understand what your source data and desired output are, you should mark them as code blocks so that they don't get reformatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query returns exactly what you want.

```
WITH MYTAB (column1, column2, date) AS
(
VALUES
  (1, 'a', '2022-12-01')
, (1, 'a', '2022-12-01')
, (2, 'a', '2022-11-30')
, (2, 'b', '2022-11-30')
, (1, 'b', '2022-12-01')
)
SELECT
  column1
, column2
, date
, COUNT (*) AS CNT
FROM MYTAB
GROUP BY 
  column1
, column2
, date
```

| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | DATE | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2022-12-01 | 2 |
| 1 | b | 2022-12-01 | 1 |
| 2 | a | 2022-11-30 | 1 |
| 2 | b | 2022-11-30 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YzA66CkW)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure of what you are looking for...

but
`select count(distinct col1), count(distinct col2) from table`

or
`select count(distinct col1 CONCAT col2) from table`

Are how I would interpret "distinct count of multiple values" in a table..

Comment: sorry i thought i edited but posted as straight line. now i formatted it